# Chrome Remote Desktop not working with elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki

Tags: release-loki, pantheon

I am using elementary OS 0.4.1 Loki.

The about page says:
Built on "Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS"
Kernel version: 4.4.0-75-generic
GTK version: 3.18.9

I've installed Chrome Remote Desktop.  The file `~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session` contains:

```
exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "gnome-session --session=pantheon"
```

I restart the chrome-remote-desktop.service.
I connect from another computer.
I see the elementary OS background image.
It asks me to authenticate.
After that--nothing.

I still see the background image, but nothing else appears in the display.  There's no dock and nothing in the upper regions--just an empty screen.

None of the keystrokes or mouse interactions that I've tried has elicited a response.

I can go back to `~/.chrome-remote-desktop-session` and enter this (after installing xfce4):

```
exec /usr/sbin/lightdm-session "startxfce4"
```

Then when I connect from another computer, I see everything I expect to see.

I can then use all the tools available in that interface, and this is great, but I'd really, really like to use elementary OS this way instead.

Answer (score 1):

Per the directions on Google's support site (https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/1649523?hl=en), I added some extra code that seems to resolve this:

```
DESKTOP_SESSION=pantheon
XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=Pantheon 
XDG_RUNTIME_DIR=/run/user/1000
```

I would check your values for those variables first, but it works for me, although the behavior is odd -- it seems to create another virtual workspace when I connect, and not literally remote control the desktop. Nevertheless, I'm able to perform any action I want on the remote system.